# C++ Find N-th highest element of a map

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, hashmap

I have a string vector `std::vector<string> list` and I am trying to find N-th highest repeated element of the vector.

I got a map include elements of the vector and repetition number of them.

```
std::map<std::string , int> mapa;
for(int i = 0 ; i<list.size() ; i++)
  mapa[list[i]]++;
```

How can find N-th highest of them from the map?

Example vector:

```
qwe asd qwe asd zxc asd zxc qwe qwe asd sdf asd fsd
```

if N is 2, I need an out put like

```
asd 5
qwe 4
```

Comment: You might want to consider [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead, [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) it on the value, and get the n:th first elements?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have no experience with map and please guide me about how can I add members of the vector to an unordered_map? Is it same with map?

Comment: I suggest you follow the link to the reference. But in short, the interface is almost exactly the same as for `std::map`.

Comment: Implementing your own [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), which can outperform stl, if needed. But they generally require random access on the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort):

```
std::map<std::string, std::size_t>
compute_frequencies(const std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::size_t> res;
    for(const auto& word : words) {
        res[word]++;
    }
    return res;    
}

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::size_t>>
as_vector(const std::map<std::string, std::size_t>& m)
{
    return {m.begin(), m.end()};
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<std::string> words{
        "qwe", "asd", "qwe", "asd", "zxc", "asd",
        "zxc", "qwe", "qwe", "asd", "sdf", "asd", "fsd"
    };
    auto frequencies = as_vector(compute_frequencies(words));
    std::partial_sort(frequencies.begin(), frequencies.end(), frequencies.begin() + 2,
        [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
            return lhs.second > rhs.second;    
        });
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 2; ++i) {
        std::cout << frequencies[i].first << " " << frequencies[i].second << std::endl;  
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/KeFao5)